# Ubuntu 10.04 vmware guest keyboard problems

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, vmware-player

There is a keyboard input problem using Ubuntu 10.04 as a guest in VMWare.
I found a website [here](http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/keyboard-issues-with-ubuntu-lucid-10-04-and-vmware-workstation-7-0/) that explained howto get around this problem in Kubuntu (which uses the KDM login manager.

How can I accomplish the same using regular Ubuntu 10.04 (which uses the GDM login manager)?

**Edit**: I have tried to use the on-screen keyboard, but it automatically closes after selecting the on-screen keyboard option from Universal Access Preferences.

Comment: I had the on-screen keyboard close on one VM as well. I rebooted and the keyboard was up and working next time around (Ubuntu is sometimes like Windows... *cough*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the virtual keyboard to log in the first time, then edited the same file.  At the login console, click on the "little dude in a circle" icon at the bottom to access Universal Access Preferences. From there you can turn on the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Indeed, the Virtual Keyboard required a reboot of my VM after enabling on my box.

Answer (score 1):

try hitting ctrl + g. I used the virtual keyboard to login and vmware told me to hit ctrl + g to allow input, and now the keyboard input is functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the same procedure on ubuntu 10.04, which contains /etc/default/console-setup

Comment: The problem is that GDM doesn't offer the same way to exit to a console login that KDM does (that I know of). 

There may be a keyboard shortcut to do this, but that doesn't really help when keyboard input isn't working. I can't get the onscreen keyboard to show up either.

Comment: enable bridged networking and ssh to the guest and change it.

Comment: It's a fresh install and I don't have ssh setup yet. Otherwise a great idea.

Comment: Well, there is another way, which I have not tried but will work. Shutdown that vm. Mount that vmdk image and change that entry. Unmount it and boot back.

http://www.jameslittle.me.uk/how-to-mount-vmdk-files-in-linux/